# Display marker using gmaps4jsf(not google api)

Tags: gmaps4jsf

I am using gmaps4jsf jar and trying to display marker on map. Marker is displaying fine but not automatic zoom functionality. every time i need to vary zoom value so is there any option in gmaps4jsf so that we can get auto zoom functionality?

```
<m:map latitude="10.132567" longitude="10.132567" height="400px" width="400px" zoom="6">
    <ui:repeat var="p" value="#{pointBean.points2}" varStatus="status" offset="0" step="1" size="#{pointBean.points2.size()}">
         <m:marker latitude="#{p.latitude}" longitude="#{p.longitude}" >
             <m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="#{p.latitude}-#{p.longitude}" />
          </m:marker>
    </ui:repeat>                  
</m:map>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `autoReshape="true"` in map tag like,

```
<m:map autoReshape="true">.....</map>
```

autoReshape just do adjust marker on map and you will get marker display only.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, It's Working. You are genius :) :):D